# does rsync work differently from Mac to Mac-formatted hard drive v. with Linux

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to figure out if this `rsync` behavior I'm noticing is specific to copying from a Mac to a Mac-formatted hard drive v. with e.g. a Synology system.

Typically, I've been using `rsync` to copy files from my my Mac to synology.  Suppose both folders are in sync.  I notice that when I do the `-avn` dry run, it lists all the directories.  However, when I just noticed that when I tried to `rsync` to a Mac-formatted hard drive, it doesn't even list the directories.

Has anyone encountered this type of behavior before?

Comment: Can you add the specific commands you are using in each case (and also indicate which command is run on OS X and which on a Linux system)? Also `rsync --version` on both system would be interesting.

Comment: `rsync` is version 2.6.9.  I'm running the `rsync` command on Terminal on my Mac.  Command is `rsync -av` source.directory target.directory